# DDEV-Local project shows "disk full error" error but I have plenty of disk space

Tags: ddev

Windows 10

I've set up a number of local sites running with DDev however I'm now regularly running into a problem when I run DDev Composer Install

[image]

I can fix this issue by running `ddev composer clear-cache` but that's not ideal as I have to run multiple steps and then it takes much longer to do composer install.

Additionally if I run `composer install` from my host machine I don't have any issues.

How can I resolve this? Is there a way to increase the disk space alloted to the DDev containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docker disk space is filled up. You don't say what OS you're working on, but on macOS or Windows you can just increase it using the GUI. On Docker Toolbox it's more involved.

You can also clean up by deleting images (`ddev delete images`) and volumes (but will lose your databases), `docker system prune --volumes`.

But it's easier just to expand your docker disk image space.

[image: Increase docker file space]

Comment: I did say Windows 10 - it's the first line.
How do I expand my docker space?

Comment: If you're on Win10 Pro with Docker Desktop for Windows, Click the cute little Docker whale in your system tray, then Settings, Resources -> Advanced, Disk Image Size. I only have a machine with Docker edge on it right now, your setup may be slightly different. Added picture to the answer